# SSH - npm seems to break ssh non-pty shells

Tags: node.js, shell, ssh, npm, pty

I am developing a library/tool which lets the user execute arbitrary commands via SSH. Overall, this lib/tool will serve as software deployment tool, which needs access to remote machines to execute several commands (cd, mkdir, git ..., *npm install*, scp, etc).

While it basically works to execute remote commands via SSH, it seems that every time the command `npm install` is executed, the SSH connection gets **terminated**. I cannot tell what is causing this, but this very simple `Node.js` script can demonstrate it:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const bat = spawn('ssh', ['-T', '-oRequestTTY=no', '-oBatchMode=yes', 'user@host']);

bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => console.log('STDOUT: ' + data.toString()));
bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => console.log('STDERR: ' + data.toString()));
bat.on('exit', (code) => console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`));

setTimeout(() => {
    bat.stdin.write('pwd -P\n');
    bat.stdin.write('cd someDir\n');
    bat.stdin.write('npm install\n');

    setTimeout(() => bat.stdin.write('pwd -P\n'), 2000);
}, 2000);
```

This will break/terminate the forked SSH process after `npm install`, so the delayed `pwd -P` will also fail. Removing the `npm install` command will make the SSH process stay intact until the app is terminated by the user.

I have actually faced this problem when I was working with the c library `libssh`, which had the very same issue, although I failed to notice that the `npm install` command seems to actually trigger the problem. See this related post: [Channel in libssh gets closed for no obvious reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784514/channel-in-libssh-gets-closed-for-no-obvious-reason?noredirect=1#comment74611459_43784514)

What I found out is:
 1. I am using a non-pty SSH shell
 2. The `libssh`packet-level debug output shows a packet 98 sent by the server just before the connection is closed
 3. According to the RFC, packet 98 is `SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST`, which *can* also be used to request a **pty**

So my asumption is, that I am working on a non-pty shell over SSH, and that something in the `npm` programm directly or indirectly leads to a server-side request for a pty, which cannot be handled by the non-pty shell I am working on, and thus, the SSH connection is closed on protocol-level.

Now my question is, what could be causing this, and is there a way to get rid of this problem?

---

**Update may 29th**

Actually, I was able to investigate this issue further. I started editing `npm-cli.js` and commented out everything, then step-by-step uncommented the lines, to see what is going to trigger the above behaviour.
At first, it seemed like the set-blocking module included via `npmlog` was causing the issue, but after also commenting out the actual code of set-blocking in *index.js:4* (which is only `stream._handle.setBlocking(blocking)`), the bad behaviour still occurs, which confused the fuck out of me. Experimenting further revealed that actually the single piece of `process.stdout` is causing the whole issue.

To verify, I did the following:

- Comment-out lines 22-94 in npm-cli.js. Executing npm install now will essentially do nothing. Also, running my example program above will not have the error.
- Add the following code to *npm-cli.js:19*: `if (process.stdout) ;`. This also essentially does nothing, but it leads to the error occur again if executing the above test program.
- Do the opposite test and change `if (process.stdout) ;` to `if (process) ;` - the test program will now run again without error.

So basically the above Node.js testprogram which demonstrates the error can be changed so that instead of `npm install` a simple oneline script is invoked, which results in the same error:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const bat = spawn('ssh', ['user@host']);

setTimeout(() => {
    bat.stdin.write('node test.js\n');        // this breaks it

    setTimeout(() => bat.stdin.write('pwd -P\n'), 2000);
}, 2000);
```

With `test.js` containing:

```
if (process.stdout) ;  // only this line
```

I dont know how the process global object is constructed, or what is going on here, but something in Node.js' process/process.stdout object is somehow breaking SSH connections. I therefore think this is not an actual issue of npm, only indirectly.

Could anyone help to clarify?

Comment: It seems very unlikely that the ssh server is asking the client for a tty and then terminating the session. SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST is also used by the server to communicate the remote session's exit status back to the client. My guess is that npm is doing something that causes your remote shell instance to exit or crash, and the remote ssh server is just shutting down the session.

Comment: But it will work without problems when I just normally log on to the host with my mac terminal, as it will for thousands of users. `npm install` will just run, then exit with 0 as `echo $?` indicates. But maybe your idea is right, I see this in the `libssh` debug output: `ssh_packet_process:  Dispatching handler for packet type 98
channel_rcv_request:  received exit-status 0
ssh_packet_process: Dispatching handler for packet type 96
channel_rcv_eof: Received eof on channel (43:0)
ssh_packet_process: Dispatching handler for packet type 97
channel_rcv_close: Received close on channel`

Comment: Added more information as I investigated the issue further. The issues seems not to be `npm` but node itself, as a very simple node.js app just plain containing `if (process.stdout) ;` will cause the error, while not "touching" the stdout/sterr streams property will avoid the error.